# NAT static IP config Unable to ping linux vm from windows host

Tags: linux, networking, vmware, nat, ipconfig

I could ping windows from ubuntu vm but when I ping ubuntu from windows host.
I getting unreachable error message.

From ubuntu to windows

```
root@arihant:/home/pavan# ping windows
PING windows (192.168.2.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from windows (192.168.2.9): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.545 ms

root@arihant:/home/pavan# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.196.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s19-in-f110.1e100.net (216.58.196.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=11.1 ms
```

unable ping from windows to ubuntu

```
C:\Users\user>ping 10.0.0.1
Pinging 10.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

IP config details

```
root@arihant:/home/pavan# nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ens33
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:0C:29:7C:F0:EA
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Static Connection
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.0.0.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.8.2
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.8.2
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::bd50:764f:15f:9554/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

However when I leave the IP config to auto I am able to ping both ways

IP config details

```
root@arihant:/home/pavan# nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ens33
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:0C:29:7C:F0:EA
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Auto
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.8.132/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.8.2
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.8.2
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          localdomain
**IP4.WINS[1]:                            192.168.8.2**
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::d18a:fae3:2a3e:b46f/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

Please let me know how can I configure IP4.WINS[1] on static IP

Comment: What vmware product are you using? How did you set up the network parameters? In the first case it is normal that you cant ping as your gateway is not in the same network (10.0.0.1 and 192.168.8.2) - a gateway is the window to the outside world so it has to be reachable within the network. It is not the WINS parameter which allows you to ping.

Comment: I am using VMware® Workstation 12. Setting the IP starting with 192.168.8.3 has resolved the issue for me thanks a lot. as you noticed It was not within the range.